# Using static::method() within an anonymous function produces different results between PHP versions

Tags: php, oop, scope

On PHP 5.3.3, the code below will fail with the following error.

> Cannot access static:: when no class scope is active

I understand that this is because the anonymous function creates its own scope and is not within the scope of the class.
So what makes it work in PHP 5.5.0? Does it also work in PHP 5.4? What would be the solution for PHP 5.3 to not explicitly call `PathController::do_something()`

```
<?php

class PathController
{
    public function get_route()
    {
        return Response::json(Cache::remember('route_point', 10, function() {
            $type_count = array();
            foreach (array("Sprint", "Score", "Section") as $type) {
                $type_count[$type] = static::do_something($type);
            }

            return $type_count;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: IIRC PHP 5.4 introduced scope inheritance by anonymous functions. Is `::do_something` `public` or `protected`? The workaround very much hinges on that criterium.

Comment: @deceze it's a public method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For public methods, the workaround is basically the same as for `$this` scope in PHP 5.3:

```
$class = get_called_class();
$that  = $this;

return Response::json(..., function () use ($class, $that) {
   ...
   call_user_func(array($class, 'do_something_static'), $type);
   $that->do_something_non_static($type);
   ...
});
```

That won't work with non-public methods and there's no real elegant workaround for that.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about your workaround. Would you recommend `get_called_class()` over `__CLASS__` ?

Comment: If you want `static` behavior, you need `get_called_class`. `__CLASS__` would give you the behavior of `self`.